# Angular js dropdown selected Item bind

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

```
var id2Search = res[i].AccountablePerson;
var foundItem = $filter('filter')($scope.Receptionist_list, { EmpId: parseInt(id2Search) }, true)[0];
var index = $scope.Receptionist_list.indexOf(foundItem);
$scope.ReceptionPer = $scope.Receptionist_list[index];
```

This code working fine on Firefox but not in Chrome,
the error I get is: `Cannot read property 0 of undefined`

Any Suggestions?

Comment: Can you provide more code and error log ?

Comment: just check what's wrong with your array it looks like it's undefined

Comment: For better programming style you should check your indices. What if indexOf() returns -1 if the item is not in the list? Then the next line crashes. Try debugging and stepping through this line by line to see why your array is undefined.